# How to debug why a C program output is wrong?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I was trying to solve this
[leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/) in C and this is the code I came up with:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */

#include <math.h>

struct ListNode *addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode *l1, struct ListNode *l2) {
    struct ListNode *temp;
    struct ListNode *sum = NULL;  
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    temp = l1;
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        num1 = num1 + (temp->val * pow(10, i));
        i++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp = l2;
    i = 0;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        num2 = num2 + (temp->val * pow(10, i));
        i++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    int add = num1 + num2;
    int tem = add;
    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; tem > 0; i++) {
        tem = tem / 10;
    }
    if (add == 0) {
       struct ListNode *new = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));  
       new->val = 0;
       new->next = sum;
       sum = new;
    }
    while (add > 0 && i > 0) {
       struct ListNode *new = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));  
       new->val = add / pow(10, (i - 1));
       new->next = sum;
       i--;
       add = add % (int)(pow(10, i));
       sum = new;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I can't figure out why the output is null for the testcase l1 = [9];
l2 = [1,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]. It is correct in many of the test cases, but the problem seems to be with test cases where add is a multiple of 10 (probably).

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) Use together with pencil and paper to draw your lists and the changes you make to them.

Comment: Please revise question to be self-contained.  What is the `struct ListNode`?

Comment: The point is to support arbitrary large numbers and using `pow()` and stuffing it into an integer limits you to INT_MAX (2^31-1).

Comment: Is your question really how to debug it?  Or are you after a solution?  Debug techniques is a rather different matter than just what is wrong with this code, but by presenting already flawed code, you are going to get solutions to the problem, not information on debugging - a few fish, but no fishing net.  To answer the question about debugging, _not_ by entering and running your code on leetcode I suggest.  Most online coding tools lack any kind of debug support.  Use a local toolchain to develop and debug and paste the final solution into leetcode (if you must).

Comment: ... if you cannot install a toolchain (with debugger) locally, then https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler is an option.  It has rudimentary debugging via GDB (single step, breakpoints, variable watch) and is great for quick hacks when you have no toolchain installed (or are using a Chromebook perhaps).

Comment: You got a couple of good answers.  Please accept the best one by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

The point of using a `ListNode` is support arbitrary large values.  When you store the value in `int num1` and `int num2` defeats the entire purpose as it's limited to `INT_MAX` which is `2147483647` (10 digits) on my system and greater than `num2`.  Signed overflow is undefined behavior.

As each digit caries less than 4 bits of information I used an `unsigned char` (1 byte) instead of an `int` (4 bytes on my system) for each `ListNode::val`.

(Not fixed) `createDigit()` could leave rely on caller to initialize `next`.  In this case `createNumber()` and `addTwoNumbers()` would do `tail->next = NULL` just before returning.  This would be faster but less safe.

(Not fixed) `free()` both arguments and the return value from `addTwoNumbers()` in `main()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// head of list is the least significant digit
struct ListNode {
    unsigned char val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

struct ListNode *createDigit(struct ListNode *prev, unsigned char val) {
    struct ListNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);
    if(!newNode) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    newNode->val = val;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if(prev) prev->next = newNode;
    return newNode;
}

struct ListNode *createNumber(size_t n, const unsigned char vals[n]) {
    if(!n) return NULL;
    struct ListNode *head = NULL;
    for(struct ListNode *tail = NULL; size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tail = createDigit(tail, vals[i]);
        if(!head) head = tail;
    }
    return head;
}

void printNumber(const struct ListNode *n) {
    for(; n; n = n->next)
        printf("%d", n->val);
    printf("\n");
}

struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2) {
    struct ListNode *head = NULL;
    unsigned char carry = 0;
    for(struct ListNode *tail = NULL; l1 || l2 || carry; l1 = l1 ? l1->next : NULL, l2 = l2 ? l2->next : NULL) {
        unsigned char sum = (l1 ? l1->val : 0) +
            (l2 ? l2->val : 0) +
            carry;
        tail = createDigit(tail, sum % 10);
        if(!head) head = tail;
        carry = sum / 10;
    }
    return head;
}

int main(void) {
    printNumber(
        addTwoNumbers(
            createNumber(1, (unsigned char []) {9}),
            createNumber(10, (unsigned char []) {1,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9})
        )
    );
}
```

and example output:

```
00000000001
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is inadequate: the list may represent a number that exceeds the range of type `int`, or all available integer types as the list is specified as having up to 100 nodes. Converting the list to the number it represents will have undefined behavior for lists longer than 9 or 10 nodes.  It is usually inappropriate and error prone to use floating point functions such as `pow` to perform integer calculations.

You should instead allocate a new list with one node for each digit, containing the sum of the corresponding digits of the argument lists, reduced modulo 10 and propagate the carry to the next node.

When you reach the end of one of the lists, keep propagating the carry for the other list and stop when you reach the end of that list, allocating one extra node of the carry is still non zero.

Note that the problem statement is does not specify that you should allocate a new list and since the arguments are not specified as `const struct ListNode *`, you could decide to modify one of the lists in place and return a pointer to its head node.  This would be made more explicit by specifying one of the argument as `const` and not the other.

Here is a simple solution:

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

struct ListNode *addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode *l1, struct ListNode *l2) {
    struct ListNode *head = NULL;  
    struct ListNode *tail = NULL;  
    int carry = 0;
    while (l1 || l2 || carry) {
        struct ListNode *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
        if (node == NULL) {
            /* allocation error: free partially allocated number and
             *  return NULL.
             */
            while (head) {
                node = head;
                head = head->next;
                free(node);
            }
            break;
        }
        node->next = NULL;
        /* compute the value of the sum digit and update the carry */
        int digit = carry;
        if (l1) {
            digit += l1->val;
            l1 = l1->next;
        }
        if (l2) {
            digit += l2->val;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
        node->val = digit % 10;
        carry = digit / 10;
        /* append the node */
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = node;
        } else {
            tail->next = node;
        }
        tail = node;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: @Vasudev Srivastava: i updated the answer with a simple implementation, I hope you took advantage of the last 10 hours to finalize it yourself from the skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you look upon the lists and then go through them one by one, no need to make it complicated with power etc. Just do as you would have done with paper and pencil.

```
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    ListNode* result = nullptr;
    ListNode* last = nullptr;
    int val{0};
    int carry{0};
    while (l1 || l2)
    {
      val = carry; 
      if (l1) val += l1->val;
      if (l2) val += l2->val;
      carry = 0;

      if (val > 9)
      {
        carry = 1;
        val -= 10;
      }

      auto* r = new ListNode(val);
      if (result == nullptr) 
      { 
        result = last = r; 
      }
      else
      {
        last->next = r;
        last = r;
      }
      if (l1) l1 = l1->next;
      if (l2) l2 = l2->next;
    }
    if (carry)
    {
      last->next = new ListNode(m_carry);
    }
    return result;
}
```